# How can I solve Asp.Net Datatable calling Script Error?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datatables

I wanted to use Javascript function at datatable at ASP.NET. But when user deleting item, application couldn't find script and giving error like 'DeleteRow is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick'. Can you give an idea to fix problem? Thank you in advance..

My Datatable is

```html
    <table id="dataTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" width="100%">
      <thead>
             <tr>
                 <th>Course Name</th>
                 <th></th>
                 <th></th>
             </tr>
      </thead>
<tbody>
       @foreach (var academicCourse in Model.AcademicCourses)
       {
           <tr>
                 <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => academicCourse.Course_name)</td>
                 <td><a class='btn btn-outline-primary' asp-action="Update" asp-route-courseId="@academicCourse.Course_id">Update</a></td>
                 <td><a class='btn btn-danger' onclick=DeleteRow(@academicCourse.Course_id)>Delete</a></td>
           </tr>
       }
</tbody>
</table>
```

My Script is

```html
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#dataTable").dataTable({
                    "language": {
                        "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Turkish.json"
                    },
                    "searching": true,
                    "ordering": true,
                    "paging": true,
                    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                    "pageLength": 10,
                    "responsive": true,
                    "columnDefs": [{
                        "targets": 3,
                        "orderable": false
                    }]
                });
        
        
            });
        </script>
}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
                function DeleteRow(id) {
                    if (confirm("Are You sure to delete this record..?")) {
                        jQuery.ajax({

                            type: 'POST',
                            url: '@Url.Action("delete", "AcademicCourse")',
                            data: { "courseId": id },
                            datatype: 'JSON',
                            success: function (response) {
                                if (response == "success") {
                                    window.location.reload();
                                }
                            },
                            error: function (msg) {
                                alert(msg.responseText);
                            }

                        });
                    }
                }
         </script>
```

Comment: `DeleteRow` only exists within the scope of the function passed to `$(document).ready()`.  Move it outside of that function so it's in global scope.

Comment: @David I tried it but I had the same error.

Comment: Please update the question to indicate the updated code.

Comment: You did *the exact opposite* of what was suggested.  Wrapping `DeleteRow` in a function makes its scope local to only that function.  Wrapping it in *another function* does the same thing for the same reason.  If you want `DeleteRow` to be in global scope, move it to global scope.  *Outside* of any function (including event handlers).

Comment: Note that the linked duplicate suggests a different (more ideal) approach... Don't put the function in global scope and, instead, change the attempt to *reference* the function from global scope.  Remove the inline `onclick` attribute in the HTML and attach your click handlers from JavaScript code.  That can be done within the same scope where the function exists.  You can apply one approach or the other, but you can't mix them (because mixing them is where you started and produced the error).

Comment: @David, thank you.. I downloaded jquery with nuget and edited my code like above and solved the problem.